# Halt Enemy spawn when a specific enemy is on the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

The below script is used to spawn enemies via runtime.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{


    [SerializeField] List<WaveConfigSO> waveConfigs; //contains enemy wave order
    [SerializeField] float timeBetweenWaves = 0f;
    WaveConfigSO currentWave;
    [SerializeField] bool isLooping;


    void Start()
    {

        StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemyWaves());

    }


    public WaveConfigSO GetCurrentWave()
    {
        return currentWave;
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnEnemyWaves()
    {

        do
        {
            foreach (WaveConfigSO wave in waveConfigs)
            {
                currentWave = wave;

                for (int i = 0; i < currentWave.GetEnemyCount(); i++)
                {
                    Debug.Log(currentWave.GetEnemyPrefab(0).tag);

                    Instantiate(currentWave.GetEnemyPrefab(0), currentWave.GetStartingWaypoint().position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180), transform);
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(currentWave.GetRandomSpawnTime());

                }


                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenWaves);

            }
        }
        while (isLooping);
    }}
```

My requirement is to stop spawning any more enemy waves if a specific enemy (Ex: Tag = "Boss") exists in the scene. And once this specific enemy is destroyed, wave spawning should continue.

I've tried many methods, including stopping the coroutine in the Update method when it detects the tag "Boss". Or capturing the tag within the IEnumerator and pausing from there. But it was unsuccessful.

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well onvisible tells you when the camera can see the mob.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve that.
Checking by tag is a very slow and imprecise way to do it.

Instead try to add a custom script component for example "Boss.cs" and raise a static event when this script start to run for example on OnEnable() or on the method Start(), this event will notify when a boss is initializating, and you can do a similar event for when the boss is destroyed.

Now you have to subscribe to the static event and you can pause the coroutine with a [yield return new WaitUntil](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) or directly stoping the coroutine.